# Formatting a string to time on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got a huge (1.5GB) CSV file, with dates in it in the format 2014-12-25. I have managed to upload it to BigQuery with the format `string` for this column. I'm wondering if I can transform this in situ to a `datetime` format, without having to download the data, parse it and send it back?

I have used the BigQuery GUI (newbie) but am happy to use the CLI if this will make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some of [Date and time functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions) to "transform" string represented date to datetime

For example

```
SELECT '2014-12-25', TIMESTAMP('2014-12-25')
```

> Added:

If you feel that you really need to have your data with date in timestamp format vs string and you have this data (string) already in BigQuery - you can do just similar to below query with writing to new table.

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP(date_string) as date_timestamp, 
  < list all the rest of the fields >
FROM original_table
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this is a longshot, but is it possible to update the database with the newly formatted datetime field, such that I can query it with all built in optimizations?

Comment: and if you want to copy all existing fields and add new field, you can use SELECT *, i.e.: SELECT TIMESTAMP(date_string) as date_timestamp, * FROM original_table

Comment: That's genius. Thank you!